# I'm trying to recolour a text box on my wordpress site, but my code only works when the text area has focus

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to recolour the wordpress comments text box on my site. The following code gets me close...

```
.comment-respond input:not([type="submit"]),
.comment-respond textarea { 
    background-color: #666666;
}
 
.comment-respond input:not([type="submit"]):focus,
.comment-respond textarea:focus {
    background-color: #666666;
}
```

...but the problem I'm having is that the code only works when the text area has focus. I'm not looking to have the area change colour at all. I think I must be using the "not" property wrong, but no other variation I've tried has got me so close.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the completely vanilla case (no Wordpress) your CSS sets the background color as you require, see this snippet:

```css
.comment-respond input:not([type="submit"]),
.comment-respond textarea {
  background-color: #666666;
}

.comment-respond input:not([type="submit"]):focus,
.comment-respond textarea:focus {
  background-color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<form class="comment-respond">
  <input/>
</form>
```

The problem therefore lies in something your Wordpress setup is introducing. Without access to the site it is not possible to say what that is.

Suggest you use your browser dev tools to inspect the input element and see exactly where your CSS settings are being superceded.

As a last resort you could put an !important on the CSS settings, but I don't recommend it if you can find and cure the root cause of the superceding.

Comment: Thank you very much! Ultimately I was unable to find the source of my problem, but !important did the trick.